# Can any LWC be hosted in any external website without a user logging in?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-out, embedded-services

I see a lot online about Lightning Out, Embedded Service, and other things, but can't get a clear answer on this and I'm not a web developer so a lot of it is opaque. Can any LWC be hosted on any external website built on Wix or SquareSpace or whatever? How would the LWC authenticate into SF to retrieve or update data? What would a web developer need from a SF developer in order to use it?

Edit:
Thanks for these great answers, I should have been more specific of course. Can we have a LWC which houses a visual flow that allows users to submit lead information (similar to Web-to-Lead, just more complex) and have it hosted on an external website so no login is required? Since this would be connecting to the SF database, I assume the web developer would need a way to authenticate into SF from the website since the user is not logging in?

Answer (score 9):

LWC comes in two flavors: Salesforce-only and Open Source Software (OSS). You generally have three options regarding LWC outside of Salesforce.

## No Authentication

If you don't need any access to Salesforce, and you just want to use the tech, [OSS](https://lwc.dev/) provides the ability to run your own custom LWC apps. You can also use [lightning-base-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightning-base-components) to emulate most of the UI of Salesforce without any connectivity. You'll lose access to things like `lightning-record-form`, since they require Salesforce metadata to work.

## Authentication, Hosted Completely Externally

If you want to use Salesforce data, but you don't want to host your components in Salesforce, you can use OSS and use the REST API after authenticating via OAuth ([Web Server Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5), most likely), [JWT Tokens](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5), or [Single Sign-On](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.sso_about.htm&type=5) (allowing you to login via Azure, AD FS, OpenID, Facebook, etc). There's a smorgasbord of options available to a developer for all kinds of situations.

## Authentication, Completely Hosted on Salesforce

Communities are hosted by Salesforce. I realize you specified hosting externally, but sometimes all you want is a site to be hosted without worrying about details, and Salesforce Communities offer that option.

## Authentication, Components Hosted In Salesforce, Pages Hosted Externally

Lightning Out offers a bridged solution. With this solution, your components are in Salesforce, you get access to the missing components from lightning-base-components (such as lightning-record-form), but you have to [do your own authentication](http://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out_authentication.htm). This is pretty trivial to implement, and as stated above, a variety of different options await you.

Almost all services allow at least one of the supported forms of authentication. If you can't get any of them to work, then that service simply might not be compatible.

## Alternatives

Generally speaking, though, as long as you can upload your own JavaScript, you still have a chance with the [OAuth User-Agent Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&type=5). This mode delivers the token directly to the browser. There is some security risk of session leakage, so use with caution, but it's still viable, as "normal users" won't know how to get at this token or what to do with it.

From that perspective, make sure users that log in do not have any more permission than absolutely necessary, and that will minimize your exposure risks.

## What The Web Developer Needs

This will depend on the options selected. Most likely, an OAuth Client Id, Client Secret, Login URL, Callback URL (needs to be negotiated on both sides so it agrees), a JWT token, and/or a session ID somehow (perhaps by an out-of-band solution). And that's only assuming they need Salesforce at all. If it's just LWC you're after, Salesforce need not be involved.

## Closing

Finally, as long as this answer is, I know it may not answer all your questions directly, even with all the links available. That's okay, you've found the right place to ask your questions. Please feel free to ask as often as you need.

As you do so, though, please keep in mind that the more direct your questions are, and the more details you provide, the more targeted your answers will be. This answer is relatively broad because the scope is wide.

Once you narrow down how, or if, you want to authenticate, what you're trying to do *specifically*, and what provider you're using for hosting, we can give more specific directions to help you reach your goals. Note, however, we don't support SquareSpace or Wix, etc, so you may need to some of your own research to help bridge the gap.

Comment: Thanks as always, apologies for not being more specific, I updated the question:

Can we have a LWC which houses a visual flow that allows users to submit lead information (similar to Web-to-Lead, just more complex) and have it hosted on an external website so no login is required? Since this would be connecting to the SF database, I assume the web developer would need a way to authenticate into SF from the website since the user is not logging in?

Comment: @number41 None of that is necessary. You've chosen an excessively difficult route. Just [embed your flow in Experience Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_external_snapin.htm&type=5) and you're done, no authentication required.

Answer (score 2):

> Can any LWC be hosted on any external website built on Wix or
> SquareSpace or whatever?

Depends on how much control your website provides to use [Lightning Out](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lightning_out) Technology.

It is clearly documented what capabilities your web container needs to provide

Verify that the remote web container, or origin server, supports these requirements.

- Ability to modify the markup served to the client browser, including
  both HTML and JavaScript. You must be able to add the Lightning Out
  markup.
- Ability to acquire a valid Salesforce session ID.
- Ability to access your Salesforce instance. For example, if the origin server is behind a firewall, it needs permission to access the Internet, at least to reach Salesforce.

The last two there is if you want to get access to data by authenticating the user.

There are two different ways lightning out works

- Authenticated
- As a Guest user

For **Authenticated** use case you need to create a [connected app](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_overview.htm&type=5), and the website needs to do an Oauth 2.0 with Salesforce to get access to data.

You will need to also create a CSP setting with a domain of another website.

For an **Unauthenticated** use case, you need to create a community and make it public

Everything else is articulated [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.lightning_out)

Upon research about WIX, looks like it is not possible based on how much-closed building websites with WIX is and how much is drag and drop.

One needs some control over DOM and the ability to inject a script tag for Lightning out

> Final recommendation Lightning out is a BETA technology. There are other elegant ways to integrate with Salesforce.

- Use the [connector](https://help.wixanswers.com/kb/en/article/connecting-slack-to-your-wix-answers-account) WIX provides out of the box to work with Salesforce
- using the Salesforce REST APIs
- using web-to-lead or web-to-case if you are looking for a simple lead or case form.